# how can i use the output of one function to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Let's assume I have two functions

```
def seq():
    #here I wrote a code that evaluates the mean of a value from a csv file
    print(x)#assuming the condition in the above code is true it prints x
seq()
```

and

```
def lenn():
    p=4
    d=#I want this variable to be the value that the 1st function produces
    x=d/p
lenn()
```

One produces an integer and the other uses the output of the 1st function and then divides it with an integer to produce its own output. How do I call the function?
I tried calling the function name but when I tried to divide the function name with an integer it keeps saying that I have a None type. I also tried to put the 1st first function inside the 2nd function but I had the same problem.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `print` but `return` (`print` has no return value, so this defaults to `None`):

```
def seq():
    return int(input())

def lenn():
    p=4
    d=seq()
    x=d/p
    return x

print(lenn())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I might have oversimplified my original code, I edited the question again so you can see what my code is like.

Comment: @kvd it's the same, return x instead of printing x

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `seq` does not `return` the inputted value (`x`). Anyway, I wouldn't place `int(input(x))` in its own function. You can try something like

```
def lenn():
    p=4
    d=int(input())
    x=d/p
    return x
```

Comment: Yes I know I was just giving an example. In my code, the first function is producing an integer by averaging a value from csv file. My problem is that I can't call the average value that function one produced into my 2nd function.